# Set model from parent class

Tags: php, class

I have this classes and I trying from class Queries to set User variables. How I can do that? So after doing `$user = new User(1)` the `$user` variable will have all information of user with id = 1.

```
class User extends UserQueries{
    private $username = null,
            $password = null,
            $date_registered = null;

    public function __construct($id){
        $this->table = "users";
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
    ...
}

class UserQueries extends Queries{
    protected function __construct($id) {
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
    ...
}

class Queries extends Model{
    protected $table = NULL, $isLoaded = FALSE;

    protected function __construct($id, $debug = FALSE) {
        parent::__construct();
        if(is_null($id)){
            $this->isLoaded = FALSE;
        }
        else{
            if(is_null($this->table)){
                $this->isLoaded = FALSE;
            }
            else{
                $this->set_object($id);
            }
        }
    }

    private function set_object($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM :table WHERE id = :id";
        $query = $this->database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':table' => $this->table, ':id' => $id));
        $this->isLoaded = $query->rowCount();
        if ($this->isLoaded) {
            //Here I want to set User variables using fetchObject
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Crisp yeah I forgot to add it but this is not the issue I want to know how I can use fetchObject to set User model

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the fetch method with the [`PDO::FETCH_INTO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) flag. It will attempt to load the data fetched from the database into an existing object.

```
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);
$query->execute();
$query->fetch();
```

I do believe that it's not possible for PDO to access private members so you may need to add a magic setter to deal with that.

Comment: Why not: `class Foo { private $name = null; }` followed by `$f = new Foo; $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $f);` works perfectly, using `fetchAll`, is a different thing, then you'll have to use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_INTO, 'Foo');`, to get an array of instances